# Web Server for Android and Arduino

Tags: android, arduino

I am using an Arduino ADK with Android 2.3.5. The Arduino is controlled with the help of some basic toggle switches and button  operation from the Android. 
Now I want to control the android from my webpage so that the arduino is remotely controlled. Can anyone help me with setting up an webserver and connecting it with my app

Comment: what kind of webserver is this? Shared hosting, private vps, private server?...If you can install django, this would give you the python libraries to automate talking over ip, if your arduino has the ip setup. Of course if your webserver is a home server, serial would work too.

Comment: I'm working on such app, hosted on the Internet (with an Arduino client API). Stay tuned if you want to test it :-)

Comment: I am now controlling the Arduino through android which is connected to it via USB. The android comunicates with arduino using ADB. Now I want to have a method of sending the commands from my PC through WiFi to the Android for the Arduino. How is that possible. I am very weak in Java , so a complete code will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at appengine, it has more than enough of free usage for your need
https://developers.google.com/appengine/